# How to publish an android library? Android Maven Publish plugin

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm an Android dev and I'm really having a hard time understanding how to publish my own library.
I used to just use Jitpack in the past but it's not scaling anymore.

I'm following this tutorial
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin
But it keeps ponting me to other tutorials, which in turn point me to yet more tutorials. (How to specify a repository -> how to create a maven repository, etc)

Why is publishing a library so complex? it's basically uploading a glorified .zip file with a version number.
I think I'm struggling with the basics. I tried googling this stuff but it just doesn't click

> "The mavenCentral() alias means that dependencies are fetched from the
> central Maven 2 repository. The jcenter() alias means that
> dependencies are fetched from the Bintray's JCenter Maven repository."

What is a Bintray Jcenter Maven Repostory? The more I read the more terms are thrown around "Artifactory" "Registry" "Github packages" ? When did uploading a file get so hard.

Could someone send some useful link for publishing a simple android library to literally anywhere (I don't really care, as long as it's public and accesible to other users)

The part where I'm stuck is creating a repository in maven central (I think), I tried following this tutorial https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/
but it says I need to create a Jira project? and wait 2 days? really?

It's a rabbit hole of tutorials, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I recently published my first library on `mavenCentral()` and I went through what you are going through exactly. So I am sharing the resources I collected and it was mainly one long ass tutorial but a clear one.

Here is the [link to the same](https://getstream.io/blog/publishing-libraries-to-mavencentral-2021/) and here are some [further references](https://securityboulevard.com/2021/02/what-publishers-need-to-know-about-migrating-from-jcenter-bintray-to-the-central-repository/) if you need. Although you won't. It is a tedious process indeed, but worth it. I hope this works for you.